# Collision with sprites using intersects

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game assignment on XNA, and I'm trying to find out how to stop my player sprite when he walks into a rock sprite, using a if statement with intersects. I've tried setting the players speed to 0 when he walks into the rock sprite, but then he is stuck in his position and cannot move. How do I do this properly?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided excerpts from your code

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to figure out what the problem is without having a look at your code, but from what you said I believe this is the likely cause:

#### Assumed Update

```
int speed = 0;
Vector2 pos;
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        Exit();
    }
    k = Keyboard.GetState();        // Get New States
    m = Mouse.GetState();
    speed = 0;                      // Reset Speed

    if(k.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) 
    {
        speed = 3; 
    }
    // Similar code for A (but negative)

    if(Collides(pos, rockPos)) // whatever your intersect condition is
    {
        speed = 0;
    }
    pos.x += speed;
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

The problem with the above code is that you set the speed to `0` **after** colliding with the rock object. If this is the case, once the user has collided with a rock, even if they try to back out of it, your code will detect it as a collision and keep them trapped in!!

To fix this, we check if the player will collide *before* we move them into their new position:

```
Vector2 futurePos = pos;
futurePos.x += speed;
if(Collides(futurePos, rockPos))
{
    speed = 0;  // Will set speed to 0 BEFORE collision 
}

pos.x += speed;
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed code and response! Thanks so much.

Comment: No worries @orekideki :). If my response helped, please mark it correct :P Thank you.